# How to fill datagridview when we use JOIN and GROUP BY query in c#

Tags: c#

I want to fill dataGridView1 using this query, this query return the correct result but it raise an error in c#.net code.

```
        string sql = "SELECT bill_no, name_shop, SUM(qty * price) as [Total],dt FROM purchase_stock_entry INNER JOIN purchase_party_name ON purchase_stock_entry.purchase_party_id = purchase_party_name.id GROUP BY bill_no, name_shop;";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];


        **Error : You tried to execute a query that does not include the 
        specified expression 'total' as part of an aggregate function.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total should be on SUM() like:

```
 string sql = "SELECT bill_no, name_shop, SUM(qty * price) AS [total],dt FROM purchase_stock_entry INNER JOIN purchase_party_name ON purchase_stock_entry.purchase_party_id = purchase_party_name.id GROUP BY bill_no, name_shop;";
```

Or you could also include in dt in your GROUP BY like:

```
  GROUP BY bill_no, name_shop, dt
```